# Convert Wordpress website to PWA without Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I wanted to turn my wordpress website to PWA without using any plugins.
I have found tutorials for PWA but none of them are for wordpress. my biggest problem is that I don't know the place of the files like manifest and service worker and ... in wordpress structure and I don't know where is the place of the index.html as the start url.

```js
{  
"short_name": "",
  "name": "",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src":"",
      "type": "",
      "sizes": ""
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "background_color": "",
  "Theme_color": "",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the meta HEAD content to  your main template HTML and add a simple JavaScript block to register the service worker.
Plugins are not helpful to make your site a PWA. The actual PWA functionality is very decoupled from the server side logic that Wordpress uses.